# El contador de las vocales sigue sumando

Tags: java

tengo un problema con este ejercicio.

> Desarrolle el grafico que permita ingresar de uno en uno mediante un botón, frases de mínimo 8 caracteres y
> en base a estas hallar y mostrar:
>
> - El código formado por la concatenación de:
>   o La primera letra de la frase
>   o Las 3 ultimas de la frase
>   o Un carácter ubicado en un índice hallado aleatoriamente
>   o La cantidad de vocales de la frase
> - La frase con la mayor cantidad de vocales.

La cuestion es que ya lo tengo resuelto, pero al momento de agregar otra frase, el contador de vocales cuanta las vocales de la nueva frase y las suma con la cantidad de vocales de la frase anterior.

```
int qVoc=0,maqVoc=0;
    String maFra="";
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    int lon,ale;
    String frase,qUL;
    char qPL,qLA,voc;
    
    frase=txtCad.getText();
    frase=frase.trim();
    lon=frase.length();
    
    if (lon>=8){
        qPL=frase.charAt(0);
        qUL=frase.substring(lon-3);
        ale=(int)(Math.random()*lon);
        qLA=frase.charAt(ale);
        
        for (int i=0; i<lon; i++){
            voc=frase.charAt(i);
            switch(voc){
                case 'A': case 'a':
                case 'E': case 'e':
                case 'I': case 'i':
                case 'O': case 'o':
                case 'U': case 'u': 
                qVoc++;
            }
        
            if (qVoc>=maqVoc){
            maqVoc=qVoc;
            maFra=frase;
            }
        }
        txtTArea.setText(qPL+qUL+qLA+""+qVoc+"\n");
        txtTArea.append("La frase con la mayor cantidad de vocales es: "+maFra);
    }else{
        txtTArea.setText("Error");
    }
```

Y bueno pues quisiera que alguien me ayude porque creo que debe ser algo muy facil pero no me doy cuenta. Esto lo estoy haciendo en Netbeans por si se lo preguntas

Comment: Buen Día, estas seguro que tu código es de javascript.

Comment: Bueno es Java en cualquier caso le cambio de etiqueta no hay problema

Comment: Lo único que te podría recomendar es volver a asignar un o a estas variables `qVoc=0,maqVoc=0;`, dentro de la función, por que nunca veo que las reinicies.

Comment: Me podrias aclarar un poco lo de reiniciar una variable? es que no conosco tan bien esto, hasta podria decir que recien estoy empezando

Comment: solo asígnales un valor de 0 después de que inicias tu función y antes de tu ciclo,

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias realmente me has ayudado

Comment: Esto no es javascript, es java.